# I have to write a code that basically performs the strlen() function in c++, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: c++

The argv array is defined in debugging properties, but I'm getting accessing memory errors: '0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Any ideas as to what is happening?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 

//TASK 2
for (int a = 0; a <= argc; a++) //counts until a = number of arguments
{
    for (int x = 0; argv[a][x] == '\0'; x++) //counts until x = '\0'
    {
        cout << "Number of characters in argument " << argv[a] << "=" << x; //Outputs the argument and string length x
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; argv[a][x] == '\0'; x++) //counts until x = '\0'
```

No, actually, that condition in the middle is the *continuation* condition, not the termination condition.

You need something like:

```
for (int x = 0; argv[a][x] != '\0'; x++)
```

In addition, that loop prints out the length cumulatively where you probably only want it at the end.

The solution there is to move `x` to an outer scope and print *after* the inner loop.

You also want to only process the "real" arguments you're given, changing:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= argc; a++)
```

into:

```
for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++)
```

since `argv[argc]` is stipulated to be NULL and you don't want to dereference that. And `argv[0]` represents the program name, which you probably don't care about.

That would make your code look something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
        int x;
        for (x = 0; argv[a][x] != '\0'; x++)
            ;
        cout << "Chars in argument '" << argv[a] << "' = " << x << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running that code with `testprog 1 12 123 "" 1234567890` gives:

```
Chars in argument '1' = 1
Chars in argument '12' = 2
Chars in argument '123' = 3
Chars in argument '' = 0
Chars in argument '1234567890' = 10
```

Comment: `for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++)` ?? shouldn't `a` be initialized by 0 ?

Comment: Thankyou very much, one step ahead of you with redefining a = 1 ;)
Unfortunately I can't vote your answer up because of my low reputation...

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int a = 0; a <= argc; a++)
//                ^^
```

That loop will include `a[args]` (it's one past the end of the array of arguments) and later dereference it, causing undefined behaviour - which in your case results in access violation. You need to loop while `a` is *less than* `argc`.

Comment: Thanks, I am no longer getting the error, however nothing is outputted. I have a breakpoint at the 'return 0;' line. According to the watch window, argc has a value of 3, but argv has the directory of the compiled .exe file in red font where the value should be. argv is defined as '234 45' in debugging properties. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Did you check paxdiablos's answer? The condition in the inner loop is wrong, too. Also, the first string in `argv` array is the command used to start your program (platform specific, but usualy including the path the executable is in).

Comment: Thanks again, both of you have been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here 1st you need to count the number of characters for each argument. So the loop will be till -

```
a < argc
```

For each argument you need to count the number of characters. So you need to calculate the characters till `null value`. So the loop will be till -

```
argv[a][x] != '\0'
```

Now you can just print the number of character for each argument :)

Change this portion :

```
for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) //counts until a = number of arguments
                 ^^^
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; argv[a][x] != '\0' ; x++) //counts until argv[a][x] == '\0'
                   ^^^
    {
        ;
    }
    cout << "Number of characters in argument " << argv[a] << " = " << x <<"\n"; //Outputs the argument and string length x
}
```

here changed part is indicated by `^^^`